# Pushing values in a 2-dimensional array in a for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array

I have the following situation in Javascript
I want the end result of the nested loop to be the following:
testArray[,[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]] 
but push doesn't seem to work nor does splice. I don't want to create any intermediate arrays because **row** & **j** are database driven and their values are actually unknown.

```
var testArray = [[3],[4]]; // or new Array(3,4);

for (var row=0; row< 3; row++)
  {
    for (var j=0; j< 4; j++)
       {
         testArray[j,row].push(j); //?
         testArray.splice([j,row],0,j); //?
 }
}
```

Comment: `[[3],[4]]` - those numbers do not do what you think they do. It would probably be useful to [start with some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Besides fixing the initial array literal you'll probably want to create a *new* array for each row (in the outer loop, not the inner) and then add columns/numbers to *that* row array.

Comment: row < 3 in your code. Then how come your output still contains values upto index 3??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to push arrays to another array. This will do it.

```
var testArray = [ ]; //
for (var row=0; row< 3; row++) { 
    var tempArr = [ ];
    for (var j=0; j< 4; j++){ 
        tempArr.push(row); 
    } 
    testArray.push(tempArr);
}
```

Comment: Yes but this will result into testArray[,[0,1,2,3],[[0,1,2,3],[[0,1,2,3][[0,1,2,3]]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and actual code? And provide some sample input data and sample output may be. I can correct my code then

Comment: I have edited my answer. It should work now. Please check and accept the answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

As is noted in the comments, your code does not initialize the 2-D array that you think it does.  You need to create a new array and push it into the top-level array for each "row" that you require.  Each sub-array can then be populated in multiple ways - up to you how you access it and "push" into them.  I coded up a solution and created a Codepen for it so that you can play around with the code:

http://codepen.io/jose8a/pen/KMabNw?editors=0011

```
var testArray = [];

for (var row=0; row<= 3; row++)
  {
    testArray.push([]);
    for (var j=0; j< 4; j++)
       {
         testArray[j, row].push(row); //?
         //testArray.splice([j,row],0,j); //?
 }
}

console.log(testArray);
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you!  Also, you might want to accept one of the two answers if they solve your issue - and whichever one is higher value for you.

Comment: Juan8a unfortunately I don't have enough reputations to accept your answer. Your answer was correct and fast. I googled the internet and there was not enough  information  to js multi-dimensional arrays in loops

Comment: The solution was "in push it into the top-level array for each row". Actually to keep things simple I didn't mention initially that in my scenario j is an array itself, so I end up with a 3-dimensional array. Many thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

There's a "new" approach to get the needed array by using ES6 `Array.fill` function:

```
var testArray = [3,4], result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < testArray[1]; i++) {
    result.push([].fill.call(new Array(4), i));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // [[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3]]
```

[Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)